# Rational for the Principle of Relativity

Tags: special-relativity, relativity, galilean-relativity

When Galileo postulated his principle of relativity, it seems like quite a logical assumption. After all, velocities combine cleanly, and everyday observation seems to show that the laws of physics on a moving train or boat match those in a 'non-moving' frame. There was no reason to think that velocity affects the laws of physics? As such, Galileo's  principle was the **default** hypothesis.

However, once assuming the the speed of light is independent of the emitting object's velocity, and proving empirically (such as with fast moving peons etc.) logic dictates that observers in different inertial frames will measure the speed of light differently. Before any experimental evidence of time dilation, what was the impetus to posit its existence? Occam's razor should tell us not to suppose any new laws of physics (i.e. time dilation), rather assume the default, that according to **known** laws of physics, different observer's values for *c* will vary.
Even after verifying time dilation, why introduce length contraction, just to keep the Principle of Relativity alive? What would be wrong with having a preferred inertial frame?

My question really has to components:

1) What drove Einstein and others to formulate *new* laws of physics - to maintain the Principle of Relativity (before any evidence as to the correctness of it)?

2) It seems crazy to think that disparate laws of physics (time, length, etc.) are in cahoots to maintain the Principle. Is this some kind of conspiracy of the Universe to serve some ideal? It sounds almost anthropocentric!

**EDIT:**

Maxwell's equations describe electromagnetism as *observed empirically* on this planet. If velocity affected the laws of physics, observers on other planets would formulate *different* laws consistent with what they observed. Without demonstrating that the laws actually hold true everywhere (not having done measurements at relativistic speeds where the difference might be noticeable, what is the motive for assuming so?
Does everything *start* from the Michelson-Morley experiment, or were physicists trying to keep the Principle of Relativity around for some logical reason even without having observed it to be true at relativistic speeds?

Comment: Could someone explain why this is a bad question?

Comment: Because asking for Einstein's thought processes is not a question about physics.

Comment: The invariance of $c$ in all inertial frames is verified by the results of the Michelson-Morley experiment (most famously, though not alone), well before Einstein and modern relativity. Einstein didn't invent new physics: he posited new theory which agreed with the observed physics. Perhaps what you have in mind is the new *predictions* from the theory, some of which have only been verified recently, a hundred years later.

Comment: i sure disagree with @ACuriousMind.  i think discussing Einstein's or Newton's or Galileo's thinking regarding **physics** is on topic.

Comment: You say it seems anthropocentric... but general and special relativity are anything but! To phrase it dramatically: the hubris of Newton was to lay a coordinate system out over time and space of the whole universe and assume how it works! As you study special relativity more, and notice the similarities between Euclidean geometry ($x^2+y^2$ versus $x^2-(ct)^2$), you'll start to appreciate it more. Galilean and Lorentzian geometry are incredibly similar, and it's not up to us to decide which one the universe uses.

Comment: Might [hsm.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: Nothing has stopped physicists from reaching the grand unified theory, other than their current obsessive and absolute dedication towards the complete banning of true understanding, within the world of physics. These days, they prefer to leave any progress to that which is achieved via the practice of mathematical equations only.  For a different look at SR, go to http://goo.gl/fz4R0I

Answer (score 3):

You asked a lot of questions. And a lot of it was history based. But I'll address one:

> What would be wrong with having a preferred inertial frame?

And one problem, strangely enough, is Occam's razor. If there were such a frame no one would know how to measure it.

Ignoring gravity for this question, then consider that there might be a frame where a clock at rest in that frame measures time correctly and a ruler at rest in that frame measures distance correctly. And that Maxwell's Equation holds in that frame. Fine.

But then you find that other clocks tick by taking their path $\vec r:t\mapsto \vec r(t)$ that gives the distance in the *one-true-frame* based on the time of the *one-true-frame* and computing $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{c^2-\left|\frac{\mathrm d \vec r}{\mathrm d t}\right|^2}}\mathrm d t.$$ And if they tick at $t_1$ then they next tick at $t_2$ when the integral gives 1 second, and **not** when $t_2-t_1$ is one second.

And similarly for distances, the tape measurers actually adjust based on how they are moving. This was an actual theory before Einstein. That there was one frame in which clocks and rulers at rest gave correct results and that objects that moved relative to that frame got smaller and clocks that moved relative to that frame ticked slower. In fact we still still use truly horrid words like *length contraction* and *time dilation* based on these old theories.

But there is a problem. Any observer moving inertially compared to the one-true-frame could write equations using their clock's times and their ruler's markings. And since this new frame is wrong you might expect that they get garbage.

But instead you find that they can do physics just fine with their bad clocks and their bad rulers. They can't tell they are moving. So it becomes a matter of faith that one frame is really at rest and the others are all wrong. And there is no testable consequence of this faith. So Occam's razor comes in and says the following:

*There isn't one true frame. A good clock doesn't measure time: it measures the metric along the 4d path through spacetime that the  clock travels on. A good tape measure doesn't measure distance: it measures the metric along the 4d path where it is at rest with itself.*

The story you told about the other clocks becomes the story you tell about your own clock. And the story you told about other tape measures becomes the story you tell about your own tape measure.

Having a separate story for the magic special clocks and tape measures was cut out by Occam's razor when you realize that magic means you don't know which one to use it for.

Maybe there really is a frame where those clocks are right. But it's not science if there isn't a prediction based on it. So what was different about Einstein's relativity is that he replaced a magic duration and distance with the things clocks and rulers measure. And because of that every frame gets to be treated equally.

Maybe one of them is special. But we can't tell. So experiment didn't force us to treat every frame the same. It just didn't allow us to know which frame was special. And then Einstein decided that if we can't tell which one is special, we *can* treat them all the same.

And the consequence is that we have to accept that a clock measures something about its own path, and a tape measure measures something about the events where it is at rest.

Comment: The observers in another frame would get garbage results only if using *our* laws of physics, not ones that match their observations. Perhaps you mean that we should assume our frame is moving, and all of our physics is to  'perfect' to match anything other than the Principle of Relativity?

Comment: @afuna If the moving frame used their clocks and their rulers and the same laws we used, you might naively expect them to get garbage since their clocks and rulers don't agree with the correct *one-true-frame*. But it turns out their predictions come out fine, they come out just like ours. My point is that there could be one true frame whose clocks and rulers measure actual durations and distances correctly and every other clock and ruler is wrong. But since we can't experimentally tell which inertially moving frame is the one true frame, then it is unscientific to propose one true frame.

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking, because Galilean relativity was logically inconsistent with electromagnetism unless you had a special frame containing an ether with unbelievable properties through which light travels.

Probably marked as "bad question" because a quick web search will pull up the answer in detail, eg: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_special_relativity

Comment: I've read through the article, and many more. They all give just that: a very broad claim that Maxwell's equations show the invariance of *c* in all inertial frames, without giving any detail. Also does electromagnetism force us to suppose length contraction?

Comment: Try this: http://ph.qmul.ac.uk/~dunstan/research/papers%20pdfs/2008%20PTRS%20Dunstan.pdf

Comment: @afuna: Just compute the speed of light with Maxwell's equations. It's $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}}$. Independent of frame.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I still haven't learned enough about the equations, but do maxwell's equations prove that they hold true in fast-moving frame, or do they just assume so (in other words, are they based in empirical evidence that they hold true in all frames)?

Comment: What forces us to suppose length contraction (and its complement, time dilation) is an invariant $c$. Every inertial observer measures the same $c$ experimentally, and the classic example of relatively traveling light-clocks easily produces both variant effects. You seem to think we're grasping at straws or "fixing" the results, but the truth is every aspect of relativity is experimentally verified to work as supposed.

Comment: @afuna Maxwell's equations are invariant under a Lorentz transformation, but they aren't invariant under a Galilean transformation. So they don't mathematically prove anything about physical transformation laws. As a simpler example, consider $\phi_{tt}(x,t)-\phi_{xx}(x,t)=0$ where $\phi$ is a function and subscripts denote partial derivatives. This is a wave equation. It can represent ripples on a pond (a situation where Galilean transformations are appropriate) or electromagnetic waves (a situation where Lorentz transformations are appropriate).